# Swift - Split text based on arabic combined characters

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, split, arabic

Dears,

I have arabic sentence like this stentence

> أكل الولد التفاحة

how can i split the sentence based on  UNCONNECTED characters to be like this :

**أ**-
**كل**

**ا**-
**لو**-
**لد**

**ا**-
**لتفا**-
**حة**

I put **-** to explain what i mean.
I just need to split the text into array based on that

How can i do that using **swift** code for ios ?

**Update**:
I dont care for the spaces.
"أكل" for example is one word and doesn't contain spaces.I want to split based on UNCONNECTED characters.
So "أكل" consist from two objects : "أ" and "كل"

الولد : three objects  "ا" and "لو" and "لد"

Comment: `print("أكل الولد التفاحة".components(separatedBy: .whitespaces))`

Comment: How ddi you solve this?

Comment: No It is not solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
let a = "أكل الولد التفاحة".split(separator: " ")
```

Comment: OP doesn't want words list separated by space. He wants deeper split within a word.

Comment: I need split as inside word. I was searching and it was related to unicode.

Comment: "أكل" is actually is a one word.It consist from 3 Characters. Two connected "كل" and one is not connected "أ". How can I detect these two objects so that the two connected is considered as one object and the other letter is another object?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace spaces with "-" using replacing occurences function.

```
let text = "أكل الولد التفاحة".replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "-", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil) ?? ""
```

Comment: I need to split not based on space.The word itself "أكل" doesn't contain space, but there are letters that are not connected with each other.So the word it self consist of two objects. I need to detect these two objects

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how accepted answer helps to fix the issue.

Apple already provided `Natural Language` Framework to handle such a things which more trustworthy

> When you work with natural language text, it’s often useful to tokenize the text into individual words. Using NLTokenizer to enumerate words, rather than simply splitting components by whitespace, ensures correct behavior in multiple scripts and languages. For example, neither Chinese nor Japanese uses spaces to delimit words.

Here is example

```
let text = """
All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights.
They are endowed with reason and conscience and should act towards one another in a spirit of brotherhood.
"""

let tokenizer = NLTokenizer(unit: .word)
tokenizer.string = text

tokenizer.enumerateTokens(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex) { tokenRange, _ in
    print(text[tokenRange])
    return true
}
```

Here is link of [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/tokenizing_natural_language_text#overview)

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Thank you, actually this split by word, actually I need to split or tokenize by characters. I dont know there is an sdk or i should use machine learning for that

Comment: I don't think there is any sdk available for that see this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55242906/how-to-split-string-as-english-and-non-english-using-swift-4

Answer (score 0):

There is two box you can just click in first. Content automatically paste click convert. Output data automatically copied with spaces I used for this quran

```
<h1>Allah</h1>
<center>
<textarea id="field" onclick="paste(this)" style="font-size: xxx-large;min-width: 90%;     min-height: 200px;"> </textarea>
<center>
</center>
</br>
<textarea id="field2" style="font-size: xxx-large;min-width: 95%;     min-height: 200px;"> </textarea>
</center>
<center>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()"  style="font-size: xx-large;min-width: 20%;">Convert</button>
</center>

<script >

function myFunction(){
var string = document.getElementById("field").value;

// Option 1
string.split('');

// Option 2
console.log(string);

// Option 3
Array.from(string);

// Option 4
var bb = Object.assign([], string);
console.log(bb);

    cleanArray = bb.filter(function () { return true });
    
      var filtered = bb.filter(function (el) { 
                return el != null; });

console.log(filtered);
var bb = bb.toString();

console.log(bb);
bb  = bb.replace(",","");

var stringWithoutCommas = bb.replace(/,/g, ' ');

console.log(stringWithoutCommas);

document.execCommand(stringWithoutCommas)
document.getElementById("field2").value = stringWithoutCommas;

  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('#field2');
  copyTextarea.focus();
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
};

/*
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('#newr');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('#field2');
  copyTextarea.focus();
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
});
*/
async function paste(input) {
document.getElementById("field2").value = "";
  const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
  input.value = text;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
"أكل الولد التفاحة".map {String($0)}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: hi @Kamran, how do you understand the problem then? I think he wants to split them into characters.

Comment: Yes, this `أكل` should be `أ- كل`(Note the dash -). `الولد` should be `ا- لو- لد`.

Comment: "أكل"  is actually is a one word.It consist from 3 Characters. Two connected "كل" and one is not connected "أ". How can I detect these two objects  so that the two connected is considered as one object and the  other letter is another object?